# EXT Js Complex JSON Response Handling : Grid Insertion

Tags: json, extjs, response

Hello I am trying to insert a JSON record into the grid dynamically.
My server response is as below :

```
{
    "studentDetails":{
        "status":"ACTIVE",
        "subject":"MATH",
        "paymentOptions":"EFT",
        "idStudent":71,
        "firstName":"Alli",
        "lastName":"Alli",
        "middleName":"Alli",
        "grade":"A",
        "kumonLevel":"FK",
        "parentId":68,
        "userId":1,
        "parentBean":{
            "parentFirstName":"Alli",
            "idParent":68,
            "parentMiddleName":"Alli",
            "parentLastName":"Alli",
            "parentEmailId":"haigopi@gmail.com",
            "parentPhoneNumber":"3173797945"},
        "startTimeSlot":"12:00 AM",
        "endTimeSlot":"12:15 AM",
        "dob":"2012-07-04"},
    "success":true
}
```

A student having parentDetails as a seperate object in the above response.

at my client I did the following :
i had a grid with the below configuration :

```
var studentRecord = Ext.data.Record.create( [ {
    name : 'firstName',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'lastName',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'middleName',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'grade',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'kumonLevel',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'startTimeSlot',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'endTimeSlot',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'subject',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'dob',
    type : 'date'
}, {
    name : 'status',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'paymentOptions',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'parentFirstName',
    mapping : 'parentBean.parentFirstName',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'parentLastName',
    mapping : "parentBean['parentLastName']",
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'parentMiddleName',
    mapping : 'parentBean.parentMiddleName',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'parentPhoneNumber',
    mapping : 'parentBean.parentPhoneNumber',
    type : 'String'
}, {
    name : 'parentEmailId',
    mapping : 'parentBean.parentEmailId',
    type : 'string'
} ]);

var myProxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy( {
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'listActiveStudents.do'
});
var studentsListReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader( {
    successProperty : 'success',
    root : 'studentDetails',
    idProperty : 'idStudent'
}, studentRecord);

var studentDS = new Ext.data.Store( {
    proxy : myProxy,
    autoLoad : true,
    totalProperty : 'total',
    reader : studentsListReader
});
```

upon data receiving from the server I did the following :

```
handler : function() {
    studentForm.getForm().submit({
        url : 'createStudent.do',
        waitMsg : 'Saving Data...',
        submitEmptyText : false,
        success : function(form, action) {
            win.close();
            var studentDetail = action.result.studentDetails;
            var xyz = new studentDS.recordType(studentDetail, 0);
            studentDS.insert(0,xyz);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem what I am facing here is :

When the record is inserted the parentDetails are not showing up in the grid. Seems, the mapping is not working properly while inserting. Where as while loading the grid initially it renders perfectly. I created the record well which shows in firefox debbuger with valid values too.

could any one guide me please?

Comment: Two things: are you sure `action.result.studentDetails` in your `submit()` returns the exact json object you want? console.log that first. The second thing is, normally when I create grids, I use RestStore, which all the CRUD are handled by the Store itself. I do not need to manually insert a row in that fashion to get the grid up-to-date. Come to worse, you may need to refresh your grid every time you insert a new data.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very tricky issue. but I found an easy (but dirty) solution, which you just need to edit the line where you create your record, from this:

```
var xyz = new studentDS.recordType(studentDetail, 0);
```

to this:

```
var xyz = new studentDS.recordType(
    studentDS.reader.extractValues(
        studentDetail, 
        studentDS.fields.items,
        studentDS.fields.length
    ), studentDetail.idStudent); //use the idStudent of the studentDetail, so the id of the newly created record equals to your idStudent
```

---

**And here is why**

So after tracing the calling stack, I found an interesting differences between the records you loaded from `Store`, and the record that you created through your `new studentDS.recordType`.

Look at the differences:

```
//This is the record created from Store Load event
    dob: Wed Jul 04 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
    endTimeSlot: "12:15 AM"
    firstName: "Alli"
    grade: "A"
    kumonLevel: "FK"
    lastName: "Alli"
    middleName: "Alli"
    parentEmailId: "haigopi@gmail.com"
    parentFirstName: "Alli"
    parentLastName: "Alli"
    parentMiddleName: "Alli"
    parentPhoneNumber: "3173797945"
    paymentOptions: "EFT"
    startTimeSlot: "12:00 AM"
    status: "ACTIVE"
    subject: "MATH"
    __proto__: Object

//This is the record created from your studentDS.recordType
    dob: "2012-07-04"
    endTimeSlot: "12:15 AM"
    firstName: "Alli"
    grade: "A"
    idStudent: 80
    kumonLevel: "FK"
    lastName: "Alli"
    middleName: "Alli"
    parentBean: Object
        idParent: 68
        parentEmailId: "haigopi@gmail.com"
        parentFirstName: "Alli"
        parentLastName: "Alli"
        parentMiddleName: "Alli"
        parentPhoneNumber: "3173797945"
        __proto__: Object
    parentId: 68
    paymentOptions: "EFT"
    startTimeSlot: "12:00 AM"
    status: "ACTIVE"
    subject: "MATH"
    userId: 1
    __proto__: Object
```

In fact, while you load your data, your `JsonStore` and `JsonReader` did a dirty hack to your loaded data. They linearize your data. They move all your data from your `parentBean` to the root of the `record.data`, so while rendering the grid, your grid can be rendered correctly.

To know how they render your grid, check the code at **Line 827** of GridView.js

```
meta.value = column.renderer.call(column.scope, record.data[column.name], meta, record, rowIndex, i, store);
```

Notice how the GridView is capturing the values. They use `record.data[column.name]` to get the value of each fields, and this is where all your `parent*` report undefined.

And so to know how they linearize your codes, you can check **line 157** of DataReader.js

```
var record = new Record(this.extractValues(n, fi, fl), this.getId(n));
//where:
//n = your raw json object
//fi = the field items
//fl = the field length
```

And in fact the `new Record` they used here is identical with your `new studentDS.recordType`, with the exception that they `extractValues` for you on behalf, and clearly you did not do it because it's not obvious to do so.

Got it? Hope the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you. Some how I missed this thread. I got this working when I did the mapping correctly. Thanks again Lionel Chan.